# Sum results for multiple queries

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm quite new in PHP/MySQL and I need to sum resuts of multiple queries grouped.

For example, I have a table like this:

```
Toy   |  Material 1  | Qt Mat 1 | Material 2 | Qt Mat 2 | Material 3 | Qt Mat 3

House |     Wood     |    2 kg  |    Cloth   |   1 kg   |   Rubber   |   0.5 kg
Horse |     Wood     |    3 kg  |   Rubber   |   2 kg   |            |
Plane |    Plastic   |    1 kg  |   Steel    |   2 kg   |   Rubber   |   0.2 kg 
Doll  |     Cloth    |    2 kg  |            |          |            |
Car   |   Rubber     |    1 kg  |    Plastic |   2 kg   |            |
```

Let's suppose that I want to build a `House`, a `Doll` and a `Car`.
My shopping list would be:

```
Wood - 2 kg (House)
Cloth - 3 kg (1 for House, 2 for Doll)
Rubber - 1.5 kg (0.5 for House, 1 for Car)
Plastic - 2 kg (Car)
```

How can I generate this using PHP and MySQL?

Comment: Note that this is difficult because the database has not been normalized: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization

Comment: You start by normalizing that table to three tables, toy, materials, and a toy to material join table. Your current schema is going to cause you problems (like say you want to have more than 3 materials in  a toy. Then you would query for this data across a join and easily SUM() this data.  You probably also want to break out your unit description from the quantity for easier aggregation.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Material,SUM(Qty) as NetQty
FROM (
      SELECT  Material1 as Material, QtMat1 as Qty
      FROM tableName
      WHERE Toy IN ('House','Doll','Car')

      UNION ALL 

      SELECT  Material2, QtMat2
      FROM tableName
      WHERE Toy IN ('House','Doll','Car')

      UNION ALL 

      SELECT  Material3, QtMat3
      FROM tableName
      WHERE Toy IN ('House','Doll','Car')

    ) As qry

   GROUP BY qry.Material
```